# Generate triangular matrix of cumulative products efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

Take a 1D vector, for example `[a b c d]`.

Then build the following matrix

```
a    0   0  0
ab   b   0  0
abc  bc  c  0
abcd bcd cd d
```

The code I got so far does the job, but it's ugly and has a for loop which should be completely unnecessary.

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
n = len(v)
matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    matrix [i,:i+1] = np.flip(np.cumprod(np.flip(v[:i+1])))

print(matrix)
# [[1. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 2. 0.]
#  [6. 6. 3.]]
```

How can I vectorise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is concern you can consider using [numba](/questions/tagged/numba):

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def cumprod_triangular_numba(arr):
    out = np.zeros((arr.size, arr.size), dtype=np.int64)

    for col in range(arr.size):
        p = 1
        for row in range(col, arr.size):
            p *= arr[row]
            out[row, col] = p

    return out
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot
from numba import njit, prange
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view


def cumprod_triangular_orig(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        matrix[i, : i + 1] = np.flip(np.cumprod(np.flip(arr[: i + 1])))
    return matrix


def cumprod_triangular_james(arr):
    return sum(
        np.diagflat(sliding_window_view(arr, i + 1).prod(axis=1), -i)
        for i in range(len(arr))
    )


def cumprod_triangular_onyambu_1(arr):
    u = arr.cumprod()
    return u[:, None] / np.r_[1, u[:-1]] * np.tri(arr.size, dtype=int)


def cumprod_triangular_onyambu_2(arr):
    a = np.triu(arr).T
    i1 = a == 0
    a[i1] = 1
    return np.where(i1, 0, a.cumprod(0))


def cumprod_triangular_onyambu_3(arr):
    a = np.triu(arr).T
    return np.where(a, a, 1).cumprod(0) * np.tri(arr.size, dtype=int)


@njit
def cumprod_triangular_numba(arr):
    out = np.zeros((arr.size, arr.size), dtype=np.int64)

    for col in prange(arr.size):
        p = 1
        for row in range(col, arr.size):
            p *= arr[row]
            out[row, col] = p

    return out


@njit(parallel=True)
def cumprod_triangular_numba_parallel(arr):
    out = np.zeros((arr.size, arr.size), dtype=np.int64)

    for col in prange(arr.size):
        p = 1
        for row in range(col, arr.size):
            p *= arr[row]
            out[row, col] = p

    return out


arr = np.array([2, 3, 5, 7])

assert np.allclose(cumprod_triangular_numba(arr), cumprod_triangular_orig(arr))
assert np.allclose(cumprod_triangular_numba_parallel(arr), cumprod_triangular_orig(arr))
assert np.allclose(cumprod_triangular_james(arr), cumprod_triangular_orig(arr))
assert np.allclose(cumprod_triangular_onyambu_1(arr), cumprod_triangular_orig(arr))
assert np.allclose(cumprod_triangular_onyambu_2(arr), cumprod_triangular_orig(arr))
assert np.allclose(cumprod_triangular_onyambu_3(arr), cumprod_triangular_orig(arr))


np.random.seed(0)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(1, 2, size=n, dtype=np.int64),
    kernels=[
        cumprod_triangular_orig,
        cumprod_triangular_james,
        cumprod_triangular_numba,
        cumprod_triangular_numba_parallel,
        cumprod_triangular_onyambu_1,
        cumprod_triangular_onyambu_2,
        cumprod_triangular_onyambu_3,
    ],
    labels=["orig", "james", "numba", "numba_parallel", "o_1", "o_2", "o_3"],
    n_range=[3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=np.allclose,
)
```

Creates this on my computer (AMD 5700x) this graph:

[image]

Comment: Great. It might be interesting to show the parallel Numba version ;) . Using `for col in prange(arr.size)` and `parallel=True`. It should be faster for N>300 and certainly slower for N<100.

Comment: @JérômeRichard You're right - for very large arrays the parallel version is faster :) I've updated the benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2,3,5,7])
u = arr.cumprod()
u[:, None] / np.r_[1, u[:-1]] * np.tri(arr.size, dtype = int)

array([[  2.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  6.,   3.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 30.,  15.,   5.,   0.],
       [210., 105.,  35.,   7.]])
```

---

```
arr = np.array([2,3,5,7])
a = np.triu(arr).T
i1 = a == 0
a[i1] = 1
np.where(i1, 0, a.cumprod(0))

array([[  2,   0,   0,   0],
       [  6,   3,   0,   0],
       [ 30,  15,   5,   0],
       [210, 105,  35,   7]])
```

---

```
arr = np.array([2,3,5,7])
a = np.triu(arr).T
np.where(a,a,1).cumprod(0) * np.tri(arr.size,dtype=int)

array([[  2,   0,   0,   0],
       [  6,   3,   0,   0],
       [ 30,  15,   5,   0],
       [210, 105,  35,   7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can avoid a for-loop.  If you want to a nicer looking code set, you can use `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` to create the steps you want, followed by `cumprod` to attain the product, and finally use `np.diagflat` to construct a portion of the final lower diagonal matrix at each diagonal offset.  Summing the portion gives the final matrix because each piece has zeros on all of the other elements.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

arr = np.array([2,3,5,7])
m = sum(
    np.diagflat(sliding_window_view(arr, i+1).prod(axis=1), -i)
    for i in range(len(arr))
)

m
# returns:
array([[  2,   0,   0,   0],
       [  6,   3,   0,   0],
       [ 30,  15,   5,   0],
       [210, 105,  35,   7]])
```

Comment: Thanks @James, I did a quick check and even if your version works it's slower than what I created. I'm mainly trying to achieve a speed improvement.

Comment: I am not surprised, directly assigning to existing arrays is much faster than creating a new 2D array at each step.

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate_triangular(a,b,c,d):

  e1=np.array([1,0,0,0])
  e2=np.array([0,1,0,0])
  e3=np.array([0,0,1,0])
  e4=np.array([0,0,0,1])
  
  M1_diagonal=a*np.einsum('i,j->ij',e4,e4)
  M1_ones_under_diagonal=np.einsum('i,j->ij',e4,e1)
  M1_under_triangle=np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',M1_diagonal,M1_ones_under_diagonal)

  M2_diagonal=a*np.einsum('i,j->ij',e3,e3)+b*np.einsum('i,j->ij',e4,e4)
  M2_ones_under_diagonal=M1_under_triangle+np.einsum('i,j->ij',e3,e1)+np.einsum('i,j->ij',e4,e2)
  M2_under_triangle=np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',M2_diagonal,M2_ones_under_diagonal)

  M3_diagonal=a*np.einsum('i,j->ij',e2,e2)+b*np.einsum('i,j->ij',e3,e3)+c*np.einsum('i,j->ij',e4,e4)
  M3_ones_under_diagonal=M2_under_triangle+np.einsum('i,j->ij',e2,e1)+np.einsum('i,j->ij',e3,e2)+np.einsum('i,j->ij',e4,e3)
  M3_under_triangle=np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',M3_diagonal,M3_ones_under_diagonal)

  return M3_under_triangle

M=generate_triangular(5,6,7,8)
print(M)

%timeit generate_triangular(5,6,7,8)
```

On the Google cloud,

```
[[  0   0   0   0]
 [  5   0   0   0]
 [ 30   6   0   0]
 [210  42   7   0]]
79.7 µs ± 22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```